# Are there any software packages that can open and edit 3MF?

Tags: software

I am trying to find programs that can import and export 3MF file formats. I know that Cura 15.10 beta can open 3MF formats, but I am looking for a program that open, edit and save 3MF files. I am very interested in finding a more portable file format for my 3D designs.

If you are not aware the 3MF format promises to provide a "replacement" for STL files that contains the complete model information, theoretically allowing us to slice and edit the same file.

http://3mf.io/

Comment: I forgot to add the link for the Cura 15.10 Beta https://ultimaker.com/en/blog/17294-cura-1510-is-now-available-for-open-beta-testing

Comment: Semi-related: have you looked into AMF?  3MF is similar and newer format.  Both are XML based.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Microsoft 3D Builder](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/3d-builder/9wzdncrfj3t6) should have [support](http://fileinfo.com/extension/3mf) for this format.

[Solidworks 2015](http://blogs.solidworks.com/tech/2015/04/whats-new-solidworks-2015-3d-printing-support.html) has support too. A software adoption list is placed on [3mf pages](https://3mf.io/adoption/).

Comment: It looks like you're right. Unfortunately 3D Builder appears to windows 10 only are you aware of any that might work on Windows 7?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You have to wait for several moths.

Comment: 3MF consortium is developing a library: https://github.com/3MFConsortium/lib3mf  The repository started to be more active recently. According to open issues transport to other platform is not done yet. After then 3MF support starts to emerge in open source SW, I assume.